# vba Filtering, based on cells array, input cells numbers

Tags: vba, excel, filter

This part prepares, a list for printing, earlier in a code I clear all filters.
In column 5 I have strings of numbers & numbers and letters.
**In input cells I have only numbers.** that seems to be the issue

When I put in input cells numbers and letters it works just fine.

My values are numbers, so I tried to change them from string to long.
I try formatting them as text.

I tried When I manually paste those values it's ok.
I can see that VBA gets proper values from cells, it put it in an array then nothing.

```
 Dim lr1, r, f As Long
 Dim rngFilter As Range
 Dim i, x
 Dim a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6 As String

    With Worksheets("a")

        Set rngFilter = .ListObjects("Tabela2").Range


    a1 = .Cells(2, 4).Value
    a2 = .Cells(2, 5).Value
    a3 = .Cells(2, 6).Value
    a4 = .Cells(2, 7).Value
    a5 = .Cells(2, 8).Value
    a5 = .Cells(2, 9).Value
        If Cells(1, 10).Value = 1 Then
         rngFilter.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array(a1), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End If
        If Cells(1, 10).Value = 2 Then
         rngFilter.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array(a1, a2), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End If
        If Cells(1, 10).Value = 3 Then
         rngFilter.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array(a1, a2, a3), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End If
        If Cells(1, 10).Value = 4 Then
         rngFilter.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array(a1, a2, a3, a4), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End If
        If Cells(1, 10).Value = 5 Then
         rngFilter.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End If
        If Cells(1, 10).Value = 6 Then
         rngFilter.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End If
```

Comment: Quite possibly not the cause of your problem, but `Dim a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6 As String` declares only a6 as String. You need to repeat that for each of them.

Comment: you can declare variables many with one "dim". the problem is with input as a number. When I put in input numbers '123456 it works, but it's far from perfect.

Comment: `a5 = .Cells(2, 8).Value` `a5 = .Cells(2, 9).Value`, shouldn't be  `a6 = .Cells(2, 9).Value`? And did you try `a6 = CStr(.Cells(2, 9))`

Comment: Thank you! CStr worked:) I didn't know this function.